# How to dynamically define the subject of emails in mailable - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-9

Here is the piece of code. My idea is that each email comes out with one of the values/entry ​​from one of my tables.

```
public function __construct($siniestro)
{
    $this->siniestro = $siniestro;

    $this->subject = {{ $siniestro->siniestro }};
}
```

[From this place I want to get my subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0PNO.png)

This is all the code of my mailable:

```
class ContactanosMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    $this->subject = $siniestro->siniestro;

    public $siniestro;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($siniestro)
    {
        $this->siniestro = $siniestro;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contactanos');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->subject = {{ $siniestro->siniestro }};` is syntactically incorrect. Curly braces are used on `.blade` files. I think this is what you want `$this->subject = $siniestro->siniestro;`

Comment: It hasn't worked for me; there I edited, adding the complete code of the mailable

Comment: `$this->subject($this->siniestro->siniestro)->view('emails.contactanos');` you have to use it like in the build method.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the build method, put it in the constructor, using $this->subject or $this->subject() is the same

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui, yes you have to put `$this->subject = $siniestro->siniestro;` inside the constructor. just like Lk77 answer below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: none of these options worked for me guys. i really feel confused. When I try with those lines I get the error: Attempt to read property "siniestro" on array

Comment: Okay, the error is really straightforward, i think `$siniestro` is an array, not an object. How are you passing `$siniestro` to `ContactanosMailable`? Can you try `$siniestro['siniestro']`?

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about all this code? Anything not working  when you set the subject?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72180739/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```php
class ContactanosMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $siniestro;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($siniestro)
    {
        $this->siniestro = $siniestro;

        // Set the subject property
        $this->subject = $siniestro->siniestro;

        // Or use the subject method
        $this->subject($siniestro->siniestro);
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contactanos');
    }
}
```

Using the subject() method looks cleaner, but both works.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function build(){
     
        $from_email = "test@mail.com";
        $subject = "Account Request";
        return $this->from($from_email)->subject($subject)->view('emails.contactanos')
            ;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory notes to your answer.

Comment: "My idea is that each email comes out with one of the values/entry ​​from one of my tables" - how does your code ensure that?